# user defined type for strings which starts with Letter

Tags: ocaml, user-defined-types

I want to have user-defined type in Ocaml which represents strings which starts with English letter and afterwards can have letters or digits. Is it possible to define such custom type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jeffrey Scofield is right: there is no way in OCaml to define a type that would be the subset of strings verifying a given condition. You might however simulate that to some extent with a module and abstract or private data type, as in:

```
module Ident : sig 
  type t = private string
  val create: string -> t
  val (^): t -> t -> t
  (* declare, and define below other functions as needed *)
end = struct
  type t = string
  let create s = (* do some check *) s
  let (^) s1 s2 = create (s1 ^ s2)
end;;
```

Of course, the `create` function should check that the first char of s is a letter and the other ones letters or digits and raise an exception if this is not the case, but this is left a an exercise. This way, you know that any `s` of type `Ident.t` respects the conditions checked in `create`: by making the `type` synonym `private` in the signature, you ensure that you must go through one of the functions of `Ident` to create such value. Conversely `(s:>string)` is recognized as a `string`, hence you can still use all built-in functions over it (but you'll get back `string`, not `Ident.t`).

Note however that there is particular issue with `string`: they are mutable (although that is bound to change in the upcoming 4.02 version), so that you can alter an element of `Ident.t` afterwards:

```
let foo = "x0";;
let bar = Ident.create foo;;
foo.[0] <- '5';;
bar;;
```

will produce

```
- : Ident.t = "50"
```

If you restrict yourself to never modify a `string` in place (again this will be the default in the next OCaml's version), this cannot happen.

Comment: Virgile, This is exactly what I was trying to do. I am writing a small parser where Identifier needed to be constrained as 'Letter followed by letter or digit'. After Jeffrey's answer I was exploring module approach to achieve the same. But could not figure out how to do what you have done in "type t = private string  val create: string -> t" Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to answer, but I think the most straightforward answer is no. You want the type to be constrained by values, and this isn't something that's possible in OCaml. You need a language with dependent types for that.

You can define an OCaml type that represents such strings, but its values wouldn't also *be* strings. You couldn't use strings like `"a15"` as values of the type, or use the built-in `^` operator on them, etc. A value might look like `S(Aa, [B1; B5])` (say). This is far too cumbersome to be useful.